# Getting "attribute or element value is larger than specified type" error for no reason - SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors, insert, maxlength

For some reason I'm getting an attribute larger than specified in type for some of my insert statement despite that not being the case and equivalent statements working correctly!

Can anyone help?

I tired to insert 10 rows but 4 failed.

[image: Error]

[Insert Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6BZ2.png)

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ410.png)

(mobileNumsArray has a max length of 12 - VARCHAR2(12) )

Comment: Can you include a minimal reproducible example?  Including your object and type definitions.

Comment: None of the values exceed the length specified in their type

Comment: Please post the table structure, and the insert statement, *as text*; and also include the object type definitions, since it is one of those that is causing the problem. (The postcode looks suspicious with its leading space making it 9 characters; suspect that field is defined as 8?)

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the leading space in postcode - its set to 9 btw.

Comment: Can postcodes be longer than 8? Assuming it is 9, maybe it's a non-breaking space or some other multibyte character you've copied from e.g. Word. Or maybe it's a different value. We can't tell because you still haven't provided the definitions and statement as text - which would preserve such oddities if you copy/paste.